# checkbox label style and javascript onClick

Tags: javascript, css, checkbox, onclick

i'm trying to stylize my checkboxes while still using an onclick function.  I found a really great style code, but it disables the onClick function.  It basically hides the actual checkbox and stylizes the label.  The value still carries over but the javascript won't work.  Is there a way to make it work?

CSS

```
input[type=checkbox] {
margin:10px;
position: absolute;
z-index: -1;
}
input[type=checkbox] + label {
display:inline-block;
margin:-2px;
padding: 4px 12px;
margin-bottom: 0;
font-size: 18px;
color:#8C8C8C;
font-family:"Goudy Old Style";
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
cursor: pointer;
background-color: #f5f5f5;
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top,#fff,#e6e6e6);
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,0 0,0 100%,from(#fff),to(#e6e6e6));
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#fff,#e6e6e6);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top,#fff,#e6e6e6);
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,#fff,#e6e6e6);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
border-color: #e6e6e6 #e6e6e6 #bfbfbf;
border-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1) rgba(0,0,0,0.1) rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
border-bottom-color: #b3b3b3;
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffffff',endColorstr='#ffe6e6e6',GradientType=0);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled=false);
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.2),0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.2),0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.2),0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
   background-image: none;
outline: 0;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.15),0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.15),0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.15),0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    background-color:#e0e0e0;
    color:#FBFBFB;
}
```

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" name="type_of_contact" value="Fax" >
   <label for="checkbox1">Fax</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2" name="type_of_contact"value="Mail" onclick="myMail()">
   <label for="checkbox2">Mail</label>
```

Javascript

```
function myMail() {
        if (document.getElementById('mail').checked) {
        document.getElementById('entermail').style.display = "block";
    } else {
        document.getElementById('entermail').style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: Put the onclick function on the label? But your JS code looks like it doesn't work with your HTML/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The html didn't match.  When I corrected the ids it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS adding z-index: -1 to the checkbox and sending checkbox under the Label. Add your onClick Event to the Label instead of Checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Add your function on global window object.

```
window.myMail = function() {
    alert('test');
};
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Gntdg/